# How to execute a crontab with MySql code?

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a file: `test.txt`. This file is updated every day automatically. Example of text in the file:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE names;
INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES (1, 'john');
TRUNCATE TABLE apples;
INSERT INTO apples (id, name) VALUES (1, 'green');
```

I just need to set a crontab that executes this MySQL code every day at 02:00.

I know how to set a crontab command that launches a PHP file, but I can't find an answer on how to launch a MySQL code stored in another file with more than one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the documentation page [4.5.1.5. Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)

commands.sql:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE names; 
INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES (1, 'john'); 

TRUNCATE TABLE apples; 
INSERT INTO apples (id, name) VALUES (1, 'green');
```

The command:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword db_name < commands.sql
```

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! If it solved your problem, please consider clicking "accept"

Comment: A little late but, I did it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Executing SQL Statements from a Text File

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html